# How would one find a certain character and if it's found return a specific value?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

Hey guys I'm really new to sheets so thanks for the help! I'm working on some inventory data where I need to differentiate between left hand and right hand products. Basically I want to find a certain character in an cell, and if true it will return Left Handed or Right Handed or nothing if it doesn't apply. The return value would appear on a different cell. I'm trying something like this, hope it makes sense:

```
IF(FIND(" lh",a1)), Left Handed, "")
```

I want if cell has character (space)lh, true return Left Handed, false return blank. I had a different variation of the aforementioned formula yesterday where it worked in returning left Handed but got `#Value!` when `lh` was not in the name. After this hump I also need to incorporate two of statements in one formula for Right Handed and Left Handed. I hope all this makes sense, again thanks for the help. I'm in a cab right now and will provide a picture of my sheets once I get to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula (replace "A1" by what you need).

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(" lh"; A1))); "Left Handed"; "")
```

Like this, only if `find` doesn't return an error (aka find the substring), you put "Left handed".